# How to deprecate a nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have 2 nuget packages for one of my open source projects:

1. Expressive (.NET full)
2. Expressive.Standard (.NET Standard)

2 was originally created as an investigation to make sure that it is viable. Now that it is I want to wrap it up under 1 but I can see that there have been people download number 2. While the download numbers aren't huge I still do know want to cause any issues by simply deleting that package.

What would be the best way to migrate people from 2 to the wrapped up version under 1? Would it be to publish a new version of 2 indicating that it is being replaced by 1?

Ultimately I would like to deprecate 2 and indicate that it is being replaced by 1 however I have only been able to find [this](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2867) that doesn't actually show it being implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nuget recently [announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-packages-on-nuget-org/) support for deprecating Nuget packages. You can now deprecate Nuget packages.

**Steps to deprecate a package**

1. Go to [Manage Packages page](https://www.nuget.org/account/Packages).
2. Select your package and click the edit icon.
3. You will find a deprecation section like the one below.
   [image: Nuget package deprecation section screenshot]
4. Select the version you want to deprecate. You can select all versions.
5. Select a reason.
6. Provide alternate package info if this package is being deprecated in favour of another.
7. Save the package.

---

Visual Studio starting from 16.3(Visual Studio 2019) will show a warning for deprecated packages along with a warning message and alternate packages info.

[image: Deprecated Nuget package warning in Visual Studio]

---

**Note**: Deprecating a package does not unlist the package. You have to unlist the package separately if you want to. It can also be done via Nuget website.

Comment: Great thank you for the update! I am going try this out later

Comment: Is it possible to use this feature on a private nuget server?

Comment: This is nice feature but is there a way to filter to see deprecated packages only?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't own nuget server, your only option is to add 'deprecated' to description:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=deprecated

If you have private nuget server, you can also enable delisting:

> Set enableDelisting to true to enable delist instead of delete as a
> result of a "nuget delete" command.
>
> - delete: package is deleted from the repository's local filesystem.
> - delist:
>
>   - "nuget delete": the "hidden" file attribute of the corresponding nupkg on the repository local filesystem is turned on instead of
>     deleting the file.
>   - "nuget list" skips delisted packages, i.e. those that have the hidden attribute set on their nupkg.
>   - "nuget install packageid -version version" command will succeed for both listed and delisted packages.
>
> e.g. delisted packages can still be downloaded by clients that explicitly specify their version.

Source: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Server/blob/master/src/NuGet.Server/Web.config

Comment: Thanks although that is the answer I was worried about getting.

Answer (score 1):

Kolappan N has provided excellent instructions on how to deprecate a nuget package version. However as he has mentioned himself it will not unlist the package version. 
In order to unlist a specific nuget package please follow these steps:

**Unlisting a package**

The purpose of unlisting a package version is that it hides the package version from search and from nuget.org package details page. Furthermore it allows existing users of the package to keep downloading it, but reduces new adoption since the package is not visible in search.

In order to unlist a specific package version please follow these steps:

**Unlist a specific package version**

- Click the `Account name` at the top right corner.
- Click `Manage packages`
- Click `Published packages`
- Click the package name which version you want to unlist

You will now see all the versions on that package.

- Under the `Status` column click the `Listed` link on that package version you want to unlist.
- You will now be transferred to the "Manage" page of that specific nuget package version. The "Manage" page will display following sections: "Owners", "Deprecation", "Listing" and "Documentation".
- Click the plus sign beside "Listing" and uncheck the checkbox that says: “List in search results”.
- Click the “Save” button.

**Verification**

The specific package version has now been unlisted. In order to verify this open a incognito instance of your browser and move to the url of the package (without the version part) e.g.: https://www.nuget.org/packages/YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME/. You will see all versions of that package that have * * not * * been unlisted. However if you see the same page while logged in you will see all packages with their status; listed or unlisted.

It's also possible to deprecate a package version (incase you can't delete a package version). Further information about deprecating package versions can be viewed at following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/deprecate-packages